# Every group element can be produced by finite product of generators.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

For Dihedral group $D_{2n}$ where n is even, I know $\langle s, sr^{n/2} \rangle$ is a subgroup of $D_{2n}$. But how do I know that every element of group $\langle s, sr^{n/2} \rangle$ equals to product of FINITE many $s$ and $sr^{n/2}$? Is there any way to show finiteness here other than checking element one by one?

Comment: You should be able to prove that the subset  $H$ of $D_{2n},$ consisting of the elements which *can* be produced as a finite product of generators, is closed under multiplication. Being closed under multiplication and finite (and nonempty), it is a subgroup of $D_{2n}.$ Since it is a subgroup and contains the generators, it must be the whole group.

Comment: More generally, for the same reason, if a group $G$ is generated by a set $X,$ then every element of $G$ is a **finite** product of elements of $X$ and inverses of elements of $X.$ If $G$ is finite, you don't need the inverses.

Comment: By the way, what's the difference between "product of generators" and "FINITE product of generators"? What other kind of product is there? What kind of INFINITE product do you have in mind?

Comment: The answer to the question is that it is true by definition, so there is nothing to prove.